# Checking the amount of available RAM within a running program

Tags: memory, malloc

A friend of mine was asked, during a job interview, to write a program that measures the amount of available RAM. The expected answer was using `malloc()` in a binary-search manner: allocating larger and larger portions of memory until getting a failure message, reducing the portion size, and summing the amount of allocated memory.

I believe that this method will measure the amount of virtual, not physical, memory. But I got curious about the matter.

Is there a way to tell the amount of available RAM from within the program, without using `exec(dmesg |grep -i memory)` ?

Comment: Sounds like a good job interview story for the daily FTW.

Comment: Sounds like a question to test interviewee's knowledge of memory management in general - virtual memory, etc.

Comment: It is a nice one, though. It tests both OS and memory management knowledge, and creativity. One can come up with a solution without knowing anything about memory management.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are correct: malloc() makes no distinction between physical or virtual memory. In fact, that's the whole point of virtual memory: to make such details irrelevant to programs.

You can find out but it is OS-specific. For example, [Linux](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-hardware-18/determine-physical-ram-size-213382/).

Comment: Thanks. there's some good info in the procfs - OS dependent, but very useful.

Answer (score 3):

The only way to do this is to use some OS-specific functionality. Using malloc() is useless for a number of reasons:

- it measures virtual memory
- the OS may well have per-process cap on memory allocations
- allocating much more memory than is physically available often degrades the platforms stability to the point where "go back one" algorithm suggested in the question probably won't work

Answer (score 1):

this is OS specific and you should collect such information from the OS services unless you want to make your own memory management layer

Answer (score 1):

Using malloc() will only tell you how much memory can be allocated to a single process. There may be reasons why this is lower than the total amount of virtual memory. For instance, you might have OS quota or a per-process 32-bit-limited address space.

(And, of course, virtual memory >= RAM)

Answer (score 0):

Very OS specific but for Linux the information about system memory is in /proc/meminfo. You can also probably use the sysctl interface (http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/2365) to get this data in a C program.